# Impicit Conversion with PLAIN Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, casting

I am trying to create an implicit cast within WPF.

Lets say we have an enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    A1,
    B2,
    C3,
    D5
}
```

I want to swap the displayed value in a ComboBox with something different. So I create a wrapper class:

```
public class EnumDisplay
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
}
```

I populate a collection with some instances like

```
new EnumDispay
{
    Value = MyEnum.A1,
    Text = "Foo"
}
```

What we usually do create the binding for a ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding WhatEver}"
          SelectedValuePath="Value"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Val}"/>
```

Works like a charm - but I would like to use a simplified/straight Forward binding. **No Converters, no Display/Value Path**. Just plain binding like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding WhatEver}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Val}"/>
```

I tried adding a `TypeConverter` attribute to my `EnumDispay` class

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumDisplayTypeConverter))]
```

but it seems only to be used to convert my `EnumDisplay` class into Strings...

```
public class EnumDisplayTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        //never called
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        //desttype is always String
        if (context != null)
        {
            if (context.Instance != null)
            {
                if (context.Instance.GetType() == typeof(EnumDisplay))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        //never called
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        //desttype is always String
        var t = value as EnumDisplay;
        if (t != null)
        {
            return t.Value.ToString();
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Still, I Keep receiving the usual WPF Conversion Exception:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert 'bbb' from type 'EnumDisplay' to type MyEnum' with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException:...
   bei System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
   bei System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   bei System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   bei MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value 'bbb' (type 'EnumDisplay'). BindingExpression:Path=Val; DataItem='MainVM' (HashCode=30659444); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: EnumConverter...
   bei MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   bei MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   bei System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

It seems, the default `EnumConverter` is still used. What am I missing here?

### UPDATE

I created a simple converter to cast an enum into an EnumDisplay:

```
public class SomeTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is EnumDisplay)
        {
            return (value as EnumDisplay).Value;
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Since WPF uses TypeDescriptor for converter Lookup, all I have to do is:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(MyEnum), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(SomeTypeConverter)));
```

It works perfectly fine in one Direction.

But if I do something like this:

```
ViewModel.Val = MyEnum.D5
```

The ComboBox appears to have no selected value anymore (ChangeNotification is implemented). Also Providing a SelectedValuePath Property will solve this, but this is what I want to avoid!

Comment: Overwriting the ToString() of you EnumDisplay isn't an option I guess?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @KroaX This won't allow to bind an Enum to the Item itself.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair r u looking for Attention? u could just edit the glitch, but leaving a comming makes you feel better - right?

Comment: according to some [google search result](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140618/WPF-Tutorial-TypeConverter-Markup-Extension) - sorry, I am not sure about this one - there's a need to implement `CanConvertFrom` and `CanConvertTo` for some meta analysis, so that the attribute/converter is taken into account. How have you verified that there's no call to this methods? Also, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5th8ef6(v=vs.110).aspx): *Override this method to provide your own conversion requirements.* I am a bit baffled...

Comment: You're going to a lot of trouble to avoid using `SelectedValue[Path]` when this is precisely the kind of scenario those properties are intended for.  I don't think this is worth the confusion to those who will maintain your code in the future.

Comment: Mike, This is: Straight Forward questsion looking for Straight Forward Answer. Not looking for someone teaching me how the world goes round :)

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish with this `EnumDisplay` class?  If all you want to do is change the display text while still binding directly against the raw enum values, you could programmatically generate a `DataTemplate` for each enum type and inject it into your application's resources at runtime.

Comment: I want to bind enum values, but Display a different text than just the "ToString()" value.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply a `[TypeConverter(...)]` attribute to your enum type and implement `CanConvertFrom` and `ConvertFrom`. For `EnumDisplay`, you can either override `ToString` or use a `TypeConverter` that implements `CanConvertTo` and `ConvertTo`.

When WPF tries to display an instance of your `EnumDisplay` class, it'll check if `EnumDisplay` has a `TypeConverter`. If so, it will use it to convert your `EnumDisplay` - if possible to a `UIElement`, otherwise to a `string`. If converting to a `string` is possible and you've overridden `ToString`, then it'll call that instead, otherwise the conversion is routed through `EnumDisplay`'s `TypeConverter`. Only `CanConvertTo` and `ConvertTo` are used here.

When the binding system tries to update the source property of a binding however, it checks if the type of that property has a `TypeConverter`. In other words, if `MyEnum` has a `TypeConverter`. If it does, it'll call `ConvertFrom` on it. It may or may not call `CanConvertFrom`, probably depending on what version of WPF you're using. Just implement both to be safe.

Comment: *(without checking if the conversion is possible)* Why is there `CanConvertFrom`, which legitimation does it have ... According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5th8ef6(v=vs.110).aspx): *Override this method to provide your own conversion requirements.* ...?

Comment: Yes, there is a `CanConvertFrom` method, but WPF just doesn't seem to use it.

Comment: I doubt that, after trying [this code project example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/443537/Using-a-TypeConverter-for-Binding-in-WPF) and just returning `false` in `CanConvertFrom` - now the binding does not work anymore ... :/

Comment: Strange, doing that has no effect for me. I guess it depends on what WPF version one is using? Anyway, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Running on .NET 4 here ... What version are you on?

Comment: Nice hint, adding a TypeConverter to the Enum. Check my Initial Post for a progress update!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following EnumExtensions to make think easier even if **it does not implicit cast your ENUM**

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name != null)
    {
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
        if (field != null)
        {
            var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
            if (attr != null)
            {
                return attr.Description;
            }
        }
    }
    return value.ToString();
}

public static Dictionary<T, string> EnumToDictionary<T>()
{
    var enumType = typeof(T);

    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be of type System.Enum");

    return Enum.GetValues(enumType)
               .Cast<T>()
               .ToDictionary(k => k, v => ( v as Enum ).GetDescription());
}
```

**Enum**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("foo1")]
    A1,
    [Description("foo2")]
    B2,
    [Description("foo3")]
    C3,
    [Description("foo4")]
    D5
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public Dictionary<MyEnum, string> Dict
{
    get { return EnumExtension.EnumToDictionary<MyEnum>(); }
}

private MyEnum _selectedValue;

public MyEnum SelectedValue
{
    get { return _selectedValue; }
    set
    {
        _selectedValue= value;

        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Reg(() => SelectedValue));
    }
}
```

**View.xaml**

```
    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Value"
              SelectedValuePath="Key"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Dict}"
               SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
```